# UIButton background image stretched Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uibutton, slice

I have `UIButton` that was created with storyboard. The size of the button is different on different iPhone devices. Then I set as background image an image with same width and height (images assets) for different resolution. I test my app with iPhone 6 and iPhone 4. The size of my button is different on both screens. That is normal, but the background image is stretched on iPhone 4 (with iPhone 6 not because probably the size of the button on iPhone 6 is square  (same width and height)).

My question is if it is possible to show the image without stretching no matter the button size. I searched on the net and found about slicing image. But I don´t understand how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I mean not deformed (the image)

Answer (score 1):

Background Image and Image for `UIButton`, both are having different functionality. If you set background Image for a `UIButton`, it will stretch your image to fit but If you set image for `UIButton`, then it won't stretch your image
So you can try to set image for button instead of background image

To set image for `UIButton`

```
UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[btn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

To set background image for `UIButton`

```
[btn setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: But when i set it as Image it will be also distorted